# Search for first index of 'xy' in string using divide and conquer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to find the *first instance* of the sub string "xy" in a char array, by using divide and conquer to split my array into half (so array[0...mid] and array[mid+1...size] where mid = size+1/2) and recursively running my algorithm on both halves. The substring 'xy' could be in the left half, it could be in the right half, or it could be between the two halves. It returns the index of 'x' if the first 'xy' is found, otherwise returns a -1. My method is allowed two parameters, the (pointer to) array and the size of the array. I tried to do it by using a modified binary search, and the code is as follows:

(PS. this is pseudocode that resembles C++, doesn't have to be proper  just the logic has to be good)

```
public int xy-search(char* data, int n){ //starts at l=0 and r == n-1

    int l = 0; //left index

    int r = n-1; // right index

    if (n==1)
        return -1;

    if (l>r) // not found
        return -1;

    int mid = l+r/2; //get mid point

    if (data[mid] == ‘x’ && data[mid+1] == ‘y’)
        return mid;

    else if (l==r) // not found
        return -1;

    else {
        int left = xy-search(data, left); //check left

        int right = xy-search(data+left+1, n - left - 1); // check right

        if (left != -1) //if found at left, return index
            return left;

        if (right != -1) //if found at right, return index
            return right;

        else 
            return -1;
    }


}
```

I need someone to check my work and tell me if I am going about it wrong. Also, I feel like there should be a condition that checks the left first and if that fails, then the right, as we are looking for the *first instance* of 'xy'.

Comment: Are you required to use a binary search for some reason? For a binary search to be at all effective, you have to be able to discard halves of the search area at each iteration and to do that the data needs to be ordered in some way, and in that case, just look for the first y. If the data isn't ordered, you can't tell if "xy" is there until after searching. What you currently have planned looks like it will devolve into a very expensive linear search.

Comment: @user4581301 it does not have to be binary search, but I have to divide and conquer on two halves and run it on the left first (since I want the first recurrence, which would be on the left if at all) and if I dont find it on the left, I look in the right. If both fail, I return -1.

Comment: You could divide the string up into a list of all possible two char combinations in the string in a struct something like `struct combo { const char * data; size_t source_index; };`, sort that, then search and return the found `source_index`, but after the sorting and collecting, I don't think you'll have saved much.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search is used when the data is sorted or if you can be sure if one half of the array doesn't contain the data you're searching, so, in your case the efficiency of your algorithm will be worse than a naive linear search.

Even then if binary search is the way you want to go, your code has some problems. For binary search you need to pass two indexes. The starting point and the ending point,so that data is divided properly.

```
int xysearch(char *data, int start,int end){
    int l=start;
    int r=end;
    if(l>=r){
        return -1;
    }
    int mid=(l+r)/2;
    int left=xysearch(data,l,mid);
    if(left!=-1){
        return left;
    }
    if(mid+1<strlen(data)&&data[mid]=='x'&&data[mid+1]=='y'){
        return mid;
    }
    int right=xysearch(data,mid+1,r);
    if(right!=-1){
        return right;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

edit: Now the program checks left first then the right

Comment: Binary search is not required but I need to do a divide and conquer search by splitting it in halves and using recursion. Do you have some code that accomplishes the same thing doing that?

Comment: Also I can only have the array and the size as my inputs for my function.

Comment: The code I posted uses divide and conquer, and regarding your second comment, you can use function overloading and direct the two input function towards the full function. ex: `function(a,b){function(a,0,b);}`

Comment: I'm not allowed to overload either, just inputs of array and size are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you want to use divide and concur.
any way. your data might be large and you want to use multi thread and so on....
i think you can use something like this:

```
int xy_Find(string str , int start , int end)
{
    int min = (start + end) / 2;
    if (str.substr(start,2) == "xy")
    {
        return start;
    }
    if (end - start <= 2)
    {
        return -1 ;
    }
    else 
    {
        int leftPos = xy_Find(str , start , min + 1);
        if (leftPos != -1)
        {
            return leftPos;
        }
        int rightPos = xy_Find(str , min , end);
        if (rightPos != -1)
        {
            return rightPos;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

there is one thing, i divided it into tow parts. but they have one common character so if "xy" is at mid it wont work wrong.